# Read LED status on Arduino from java

Tags: java, arduino

My project involves reading the status of an LED on Arduino, from java. It will move on to reading temperature from Arduino, but I got stuck. So here it is:

I send the "Turn on/off!" message from my java program, and I want it to show if the LED is on and off.
So when I send "192.168.0.100/ON", the LED turns on and I shoud get the "ON" message in my program.

The code on Arduino:

```
byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0x2F, 0xD4 };
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,100); 
EthernetServer server(80);
String message = String(30);

void setup()
{
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    // an http request ends with  a blank line
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();

        if (message.length() < 30) {
          message += c;
        }

        Serial.print(message);
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n') {

          if (message.indexOf("ON") > 0) {
            digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
            client.print("ON");
          }
          if (message.indexOf("OFF") > 0) {
            digitalWrite(2, LOW);
            client.print("OFF");
          }

          message = "";
          client.stop();
        }      
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

The code in java:

```
public class TestClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader serverResponse = null;
    try {
        // OPEN CONNECTION
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://192.168.0.100/ON")
                .openConnection();

        connection.connect();

        // RESPONSE STREAM
        serverResponse = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

        // READ THE RESPOSNE
        String line;
        while ((line = serverResponse.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();

        if (serverResponse != null) {
            try {
                serverResponse.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

What happens: The LED turns on, but I get this error in java:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:23) -> connection.getInputStream();
```

What I want: After sending the "ON" message, it should be printed in console.

**Mention**: if I send 192.168.0.100/ON from my browser, the LED turns on and the message appears in the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Ethernet-Shield-Tutorial/step4/Server/) guy here says, the Arduino can serve HTML pages, so I guessed my HttpURLConnection must know about this. [Here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), it says that "The version of an HTTP message is indicated by an HTTP-Version field in the first line of the message."

So I simply added the following code into the Arduino sketch, right after I check (c == "\n"):

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println();
```

I didn't get to this very quickly, but after reading others` code and the resources I mentioned above, I came to this conclusion. The explanation could be as well wrong for all I know, but it worked, and my project runs.

Comment: did you try text other than in your explanation, e.g. `client.println("asdfjklasdfjkl");` ?

Comment: Yes, after writing the answer, I thought about this as well. Truns out the first line must always be there, as it is. The rest is not so important

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. If the exception is thrown when getting the InputStream, then it's happening because the connection has been closed at that point, and this happens because the Arduino sends the message then immediately "closes" the client, effectively terminating the connection. You can do three things:

   a. Try and creating the input stream before calling connect(), but this most likely will fail due to the connection not existing at that point.

   b. Put a delay before calling client.stop();

   c. (recommended) Let the client close the connection, don't do it on the server.
2. Try adding a \n after ON and OFF in client.print() method, in the Arduino code.

   ```
   client.print("ON\n");
   ...
   client.print("OFF\n");
   ```

readLine() will read until the first end-of-line char which never comes.

Answer (score 0):

Try reverse the order in your finally block.  Close the input stream before you close the socket.

Comment: If the results are the same even after you swapped the order of close order, perhaps your server is closing the connection too early.  Typically, in Socket programming, there will be a server and there will be a client.  The arduino, typically configures as a server, should stay listening to a port constantly and never closes.  It is the Java application that should act as a client and request connections and closes after request is done.  Perhaps you can checkout that route.

Comment: Arduino is acting as a server, it waits for requests on port 80, parses the request and sends back information. When the client connects, it is only interested in one specific information, and after it gets it, the diconnect() method is called on the connection. I have provided the solution, I will check it in 15 hours